# D3.js Event Drops Zoom In Center Only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-drops

I am using Event Drops which uses D3.js, I want to zoom only in the center not where the mouse is. How can I achieve this?

Event Drops: https://github.com/marmelab/EventDrops

I tried modifying the event drops parameters but nothing for center.